# Selecting nonzero rules from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

I have a list of rules: `list = {a1 -> 0, a2 -> 3x, a4 -> 0, a5 -> 5x+3...}`.

I would like to append to another list the nonzero rules, which are: `{a2 -> 3x, a5 -> 5x+3,...}`.

I have tried `Select` and `If != 0` but they don't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I append to list2 the nonzero associations of list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is a list of rules. If you want to work with associations, do:

```
list = Association[a1->0,a2->3x,a4->0,a5->5x+3]
```

> <|a1 -> 0, a2 -> 3 x, a4 -> 0, a5 -> 3 + 5 x|>

Then, there are many ways to select the nonzero associations, here are a couple examples:

```
Select[# =!= 0&] @ list
DeleteCases[list, 0]
```

> <|a2 -> 3 x, a5 -> 3 + 5 x|>
>
> <|a2 -> 3 x, a5 -> 3 + 5 x|>

Use [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join) to append to another association:

```
Join[Association[b1->1, b2->3], Select[# =!= 0&] @ list]
```

> <|b1 -> 1, b2 -> 3, a2 -> 3 x, a5 -> 3 + 5 x|>

**Addendum**

On the other hand, if you do want to work with lists of rules (as mentioned in the comments), you could do:

```
list = {a1->0, a2->3x, a4->0, a5->5x+3};

Select[#[[2]] =!= 0&] @ list
DeleteCases[list, _->0]
```

> {a2 -> 3 x, a5 -> 3 + 5 x}
>
> {a2 -> 3 x, a5 -> 3 + 5 x}

Again, use [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join) to join two lists of rules:

```
Join[{b1->1, b2->3}, DeleteCases[list, _->0]]
```

> {b1 -> 1, b2 -> 3, a2 -> 3 x, a5 -> 3 + 5 x}

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to keep the list of rules and append the nonzero rules to another list (of rules)?